# Word for thinking of the same thing as someone else?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Do we have a word or phrase for this? For example, we could have two good friends: Person A and Person B. In a conversation, after a certain phrase is said, both say the same thing at once, signifying that they both thought about the same thing/shared the same feelings. It would essentially be a way of "knowing what each other is thinking".

Answer (score 0):

jinx - you owe me a coke ;)
being on the same wavelength or in-sync

Answer (score 0):

There is no word or phrase for two persons accidentally saying the same thing at the same time. In the U.S., however, there is a children's game that is initiated when that happens (see [jinx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx_(children's_game)))

Answer (score 0):

"Great minds think alike" is a phrase sometimes used in that situation.  Although I find the "jinx" game happens more often.